# Can a distributed system designed with logical clocks truly derive a total ordering of events?

Tags: distributed-systems, clocks

I’m reading Leslie Lamport’s white paper, “[Time, clocks, and the ordering of events in a distributed system](https://amturing.acm.org/p558-lamport.pdf)”. His explanation for total ordering has me a bit confused in the following excerpt.

[image]

1. I've interpreted this as if event x's timestamp is less than event y
   then x happened before y.
2. If x's timestamp is the same as y's
   timestamp then use the process name to determine who comes first.

I'm confused because if x is less than y then there are two possibilities to my understanding; either x happened first or x and y are concurrent. It seems like he's always assuming the former and never the latter.